# Android L - Difference in BLE Scan Result in LG Nexus 4 and Samsung S4

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

We are developing an app that uses BLE functionality. This app was working fine on all devices till some of them got Android L update. 
One of these devices being LG Google Nexus 4. 
This device stopped working ever since we updated to Android L. Below are the issues identified:

1. Device scanning is slow. Returns device after 5-10 seconds even when we scan every 1 second and use the new Android L api (startScan with proper filter and scan mode set to low latency).
2. Even if it does scan the device after delay, there is difference in scan result packet that is returned. On Samsung devices (even with Android L update), we get the proper advertisement packet while the same device gives a different advertisement packet on Nexus 4.

Below are the scan result from both devices. Both of them are 62 bytes but see the difference in bytes.

We also use manufacturing data for our business logic but because some of the bytes are missing (or replaced with other bytes), we don't get the information required on LG Nexus 4.

--LG Nexus 4 (Android 5.1.0)
{0x02,0x01,0x06,0x1A,0xFF,0x4C,0x00,0x02,0x15,0xF7,0x82,0x6D,0xA6,0x4F,0xA2,0x4E,0x98,0x80,0x24,0xBC,0x5B,0x71,0xE0,0x89,0x3E,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xA6,0x08,0x09,0x42,0x4C,0x45,0x20,0x52,0x44,0x52,0x02,0xA6,0x00,0x11,0x06,0xFE,0xE2,0x45,0x7F,0x5A,0xB5,0xFD,0x8C,0xF2,0x4A,0x0E,0x3F,0xF4,0xA7,0x25,0x66,0x00,0x00}

--Samsung S4 (Android 5.0.2)
{0x02,0x01,0x06,0x11,0x06,0xFE,0xE2,0x45,0x7F,0x5A,0xB5,0xFD,0x8C,0xF2,0x4A,0x0E,0x3F,0xF4,0xA7,0x25,0x66,0x09,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x2F,0xFF,0x11,0xE2,0x02,0x39,0x08,0x09,0x42,0x4C,0x45,0x20,0x52,0x44,0x52,0x02,0xA6,0x00,0x11,0x06,0xFE,0xE2,0x45,0x7F,0x5A,0xB5,0xFD,0x8C,0xF2,0x4A,0x0E,0x3F,0xF4,0xA7,0x25,0x66,0x00}

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Since you still got no response - do you have root access to the devices? If yes you can try to snoop the hci data and compare what is going on very close to your bluetooth module hardware. You can enable these debug settings in `/etc/bluetooth/bt_stack.conf`, open the binary hci snoop files in wireshark for explaination. Good Luck!

Comment: I have root access but can't ask users to root their phone. We observed that Android is confused between Beacon and GATT adv. In our implementation the hardware does both an iBeacon and GATT. While iPhone uses the iBeacon adv to wake up, Android is only interested in GATT advertisement (there is nothing in Android to differentiate between Beacon and GATT). Some devices (like LG Nexus 4), returns Beacon adv for StartLeScan (or latest StartScan) while Samsung gives GATT advertisement. This difference in implementation is really frustrating. Haven't found a solution yet.